# What value to set as 'kid' in JWT header

Tags: jwt, jwk

As per the [JWK specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7517#section-4.5) 'kid' is defined as follows.

> The "kid" (key ID) parameter is used to match a specific key.  This
> is used, for instance, to choose among a set of keys within a JWK Set
> during key rollover.  The structure of the "kid" value is
> unspecified.  When "kid" values are used within a JWK Set, different
> keys within the JWK Set SHOULD use distinct "kid" values.  (One
> example in which different keys might use the same "kid" value is if
> they have different "kty" (key type) values but are considered to be
> equivalent alternatives by the application using them.)  The "kid"
> value is a case-sensitive string.  Use of this member is OPTIONAL.
> When used with JWS or JWE, the "kid" value is used to match a JWS or
> JWE "kid" Header Parameter value.

Can we use the certificate thumbprint as the 'kid' value here since it directly identifies the key used to sign the JWT? What are the drawbacks of using the certificate thumbprint as the 'kid' instead of a random string?

Comment: A certificate thumbprint is undistinguishible from a random string.

Answer (score 3):

The fingerprint by definition would be stable and always available on the key. So using it would free you from storing the relation between the key and a random string.

I see not drawbacks in using the fingerprint.

Comment: I agree with that answer. The thumbprint of the key is a good solution. Please note that the [RFC7638](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7638) introduces a way to compute a thumbprint for all JWK.

Comment: but since we are already sending certificate thumbprint in 'x5t' element, wouldn't it be redundant to include the thumbprint in 'kid' as well?